# Change the color of a card while mapping through an array based on it's value in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, meteor, material-ui

I want to change the color of the card based on the value of the current slot which is an object in an array. So when I am mapping through a card I want to change the backgroundColor of the card based on the value. How should I do that? My current approach doesn't seem to work.

```
slots.map(slot => 
          <Card key ={slot._id} style={{backgroundColor:slot.OccupiedStatus?'black':'teal'}}>
            
            <Typography>{slot.category}</Typography>
          </Card>
```

Comment: Is Card https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card/ ? Then as shown on the page, you'd need to use `sx` instead of `style`

Answer (score 0):

Since The `Card` is a React Component, in your case the `style` is not considered an attribute instead it is a prop that will be passed on to the `Card` component.

You can catch that `style` prop in your `Card` Component and use it.

```
const Card = (style, ...otherProps) => {
    return <div style={style} >hello</div>
}
```